# Unable to share on Whatsapp from my WebView . Getting The webpage at whatsapp://send?text= could not be load because net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME

Tags: java, android-layout, android-studio, webview, android-webview

Getting Error while sharing a news on whatsapp using my Webview App

**package com.agraleaks.imgauravanimator;

```
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.view.View;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener;



import com.agraleaks.imgauravanimator.Common.Config;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnRefreshListener {

    private WebView webView;
    private ProgressDialog dialog;
    private BroadcastReceiver mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver;
    private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        swipeLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipe_container);
        swipeLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);
        swipeLayout.setColorScheme(android.R.color.holo_blue_bright,
                android.R.color.holo_green_light,
                android.R.color.holo_orange_light,
                android.R.color.holo_red_light);





        //WebView
        webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                //hide loading image
                findViewById(R.id.imageView1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                findViewById(R.id.progressBar1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                //show webview
                findViewById(R.id.webView).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }


        });

        webView.loadUrl("http://www.agraleaks.com/");
        webView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
        webView.setBackgroundColor(128);






        mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                if (intent.getAction().equals(Config.STR_PUSH))
                {
                    String message = intent.getStringExtra(Config.STR_PUSH);
                    showNotification ("Agra Leaks- Fastest News Channel in the City",message);
                }
            }
        };

        onNewIntent(getIntent());

    }
    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub



        if(url != null && url.startsWith("whatsapp://"))
        {
             Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
        sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Agra Leaks - Digital Newspaper.");
        sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
        sendIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
        startActivity(sendIntent);
            return true;

        }else
        {
            return false;
        }



    }
    private void showNotification(String title, String message) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(),MainActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(Config.STR_KEY,message);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getBaseContext(),0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getBaseContext());
        builder.setAutoCancel(true)
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(message)
                .setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(1,builder.build());
    }




    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction()== KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){

            switch (keyCode){

                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                    if (webView.canGoBack()){

                        webView.goBack();
                    }
                    else {

                        finish();
                    }
                    return true;
            }
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver);
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver,new IntentFilter("registrationComplete"));
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mRegistrationBroadcastReceiver,new IntentFilter(Config.STR_PUSH));
    }


    @Override
    public void onRefresh() {
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override public void run() {
               // webView.reload();
               swipeLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                webView.loadUrl( "javascript:window.location.reload( true )" );

            }
        }, 5000);
    }






}**
```

These are my code 
Unable to share on Whatsapp from my WebView. Getting Error - The webpage at whatsapp://send?text= could not be load because net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME.

here is my activity_main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.agraleaks.imgauravanimator.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/swipe_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"  />





    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

 <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/splash" />


    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: AnyOne can help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found my Answer myself ,

i just need to put these codes

```
@Override
            public boolean  shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                if(url != null && url.startsWith("whatsapp://"))
                {
                    Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
                    sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Moon TV");
                    sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
                    sendIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
                    startActivity(sendIntent);return true;

            }else
            {
                return false;
            }
```